How to encode/decode a SortDescriptor whose compared value is a custom type?
Let's create a basic custom Item type with a title and a date.
struct Item {
    let title: String
    let date: Date
}

Any SortDescriptor<Item> conforms to Codable out of the box. So the above code compiles perfectly.
do {
    let descriptor = SortDescriptor<Item>(\.title, comparator: .localizedStandard)
    let encoded = try JSONEncoder().encode(descriptor)
    print(String(data: encoded, encoding: .utf8)!)
} catch {
    debugPrint(error)
}

However, the encoding fails at runtime.

Swift.EncodingError.invalidValue(Foundation.SortDescriptor<__lldb_expr_46.Item>.AllowedComparison.comparableString((extension in Foundation):Swift.String.StandardComparator(options: __C.NSStringCompareOptions(rawValue: 833), isLocalized: true, order: Foundation.SortOrder.reverse), \Item.title), Swift.EncodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Encoding SortDescriptor with values of type non-NSObject Compared is unsupported.", underlyingError: nil))

Why does this happen?

From the documentation for one of the init's: "where Compared : NSObject". SortDescriptor is pretty limited in this sense and seems to depend a lot on old NS types.

@JoakimDanielson Damn… Do you know another way of storing (encoding/decoding) sort comparators? The idea is to store them as Data via @AppStorage.

No, I haven't done something like that.
